# HTML of Email content is not showing in Mailinator

Tags: php, html, mailing, mailinator

So, As my Title Says I'm messing up with the issue of HTML Email. There is mails sending by my application to the [mailinator](http://mailinator.com/)'s mail ids. the issue is it is not showing the HTML , No css (it is inline), No fonts.

However it is showing perfectly on my private email server.

Could you guys please tell me what can be the issue with mailinator's Ids ?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED: 
my HTML is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site name</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#D85A50; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" >
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" background="{image_path}school.png" style=" height:410px;">    
                <p style="font-size:22px; color:#fff; text-align:right;  padding-right:20px; padding-top:50px;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;"> MillionInOne <span style="display:block;">School Competition</span></a>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style=" padding:10px 15px;">
                <p style="font-size: 18px; color:#fff; margin:0; font-weight:bold;">Dear {full_name},</p>
                <img src="http://bs.example.com/tanmay/shweta/email/images/spacer.png" height="10" width="2" alt=""  />
                <p style="font-size: 13px; color:#fff; margin:0; line-height:20px; width:100%; text-align:justify;">Welcome to School Competition! Your account has been registered with us as <b>{user_type_name}</b>.  You can login to your account by the following credentials.<br><b>Email:</b> {email}<br><b>Password:</b> {password}</p>
                <img src="http://bs.example.com/tanmay/shweta/email/images/spacer.png" height="30" width="2" alt="" />
                <p style="font-size: 13px; color:#fff; margin:0; line-height:20px ">Thanks, <br />
                    Millioninone</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="{site_url}" style="text-transform:uppercase; background:#DD6D64; color:#fff; border:solid 1px #E48B84; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; min-width:90px; text-align:center; display:inline-block; line-height:30px;">View Site</a>
                </p>
                <p style="border-top:1px solid #CCC; font-size: 10px;padding: 3px;color:#FFF"><b>Note:-</b>This email is generated automatically, and does not accept replies. If you are not the intended recipient, just ignore this email.</p>
                <span style="margin-left:32%;font-size: 10px;padding: 3px;color:#FFF">{copy_right}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your HTML content. But validate the content via W3CValidator first.

Comment: Is your issue somehow specific to mailinator? What about gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc?

Comment: @j08691 it is fine for gmail,hotmail, yahoo etc. The issue is only for mailinator and i have checked that other emails by peoples have the template and it is showing fine.